# C# method lock doesn't work

Tags: c#, locking

I have an exe file that needs to run multiple times.

In the C# code I have a method that reads some value from the database and changes it. I want to prevent more than one exe command getting this method.
I tried to use lock mechanism but it doesn't work

```
private static readonly object locker = new object();

private void myFunc()
    {

        lock (locker)
        {

           //my code

        }
    }
```

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { //your code });

Answer (score 3):

**`lock` is only valid at thread level** (inside one process).

> I have an exe file that need to run multiply times.

If you use multiple process to achieve your task, you should use a use [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Here is way to do it:

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex(false, "MyFuncLock") ; 

private void myFunc()
{
    mut.WaitOne();

       //your code

    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean exeFile. I also tried to use mutex but it didn't work

Comment: @Ksv3n This code will create a new mutex for each process, so it won't synchronize multiple processes. To fix it you need to use the `Mutex` constructor which receives a mutex name.

Comment: @AdiLester what do you mean 'mutext constructor which receives a mutex name'?

Comment: @Elfrat : he means the parameteres "MyFuncLock" in Mutex constructor